# How to calculate Gower distance weights

Tags: matrix, statistics, cluster-analysis, distance

so I'm using Gower distance to make some clusters but I've been trying to search for an specific way to calculate the weights for the variables and I have not found something useful about it.

In some examples they use values between 1 and 4, and in other examples they use values from 0 to 150 or more, so is there a limit? or a practical way to calculate them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can't be calculated, because there is no "right" value.

It is a matter of the data, the problem, the use case, and personal preference, which features are more important than others. There is no "objective" value for such importance.